# Pentaho - Merge Rows(diff) giving results

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using the 2 different inputs for merge row(diff) and all the attributes are in string the issue is whenever we took the small input it works find but as the input size increasing the results not accurate its comparing same rows and marking few of them as new.

Answer (score 1):

you need to order by the same key the rows before the merge diff